# ArrayObject does not work with end() in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, php-7.4

On migrating to PHP 7.4 I have to deal with a different behavior of some array functions like `reset()`, `current()` or `end()` concerning ArrayObject. The following example produces different outputs:

```
<?php

$array = new \ArrayObject(["a", "b"]);
$item = end($array);
var_dump($item);


$array = ["a", "b"];
$item = end($array);
var_dump($item);
```

With **php 7.4** the output is:

```
bool(false)
string(1) "b"
```

On PHP versions before 7.4 the output is the following:

```
string(1) "b"
string(1) "b"
```

A `end($array->getArrayCopy())` produces a notice, but might be a workaround if used with a variable.

Is there a way to emulate the behavior of `end()` with an `ArrayObject` or `ArrayIterator`? The ArrayObject could be very big, an iteration to the end might not be the best solution.

Comment: An alternative could be `$item = $array[count($array)-1];`.  Not sure if that's the most efficient solution.

Comment: I'd say that qualifies as a PHP bug, there's definitely nothing in the changelog that would suggest this was an intended change in 7.4

Comment: Test it online: https://3v4l.org/4MADI

Comment: As `ArrayObject` and `ArrayIterator` both implement `ArrayAccess` Interface, you can just typecast the `ArrayObject` (or w/e) to array and pass it to `end()`.
Edit: Tested it in PHP 7.4.0

Comment: @PatrickQ what if it's associative?

Comment: @iainn this is definitely not a bug - https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.incompatible.php#migration74.incompatible.spl

Comment: [`end()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) accepts an array and you are giving it an object.  This doesn't throw any error as it seems. But [`array_pop()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) does throw an error.

Comment: @Andreas  Then you ask a different question with the appropriate conditions of your problem  :)  You'll also not I didn't post it as an Answer.

Comment: @u_mulder Well then I take that back. That'll teach me for looking through the changelog rather than the breaking changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.incompatible.php#migration74.incompatible.spl) array methods don't operate on internal array, but on `ArrayObject` itself. I summarized two solutions for that.

**1.** Getting internal array of object.

```
$array = new \ArrayObject(["a", "b"]);
$item = end($array->getArrayCopy());
```

**2.** Creating Facade of `ArrayObject` and adding custom method end() to upgraded class.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the arrayobject an array to get the keys then use end on the keys to get the last key.

```
$array = new \ArrayObject(["a", "b"]);
$keys = array_keys((array)$array);
$end_key = end($keys);

var_dump($array[$end_key]);
```

It's not a pretty solution but it works.
I suggest you make it a function so that you can call it when needed.

https://3v4l.org/HTGYn

As a function:

```
function end_object($array){
    $keys = array_keys((array)$array);
    $end_key = end($keys);
    return $array[$end_key];
}


$array = new \ArrayObject(["a", "b"]);
$item = end_object($array);
var_dump($item);
```

Comment: I dont see difference between both answers when I look at the result and usaqe in question. if difference explain please

Comment: The other answer uses an array and casts it to an object which is not what OP asked for. I use an arrayObject and cast it to array to get the keys from it.

Comment: So, is it solution for this question ? Is there a way to emulate the behavior of end() with an ArrayObject or ArrayIterator ?

Comment: That is why I posted it as an answer. Check the link if you don't believe me...

Comment: I've tested the `array_keys()` solution with https://3v4l.org/IaEMM/perf#output but it needed 20-30% more on memory compared with an `end()` on a simple `getArrayCopy()` https://3v4l.org/uYv59/perf#output

Comment: @Trendfischer my understanding of the performance tab on 3v4l is that it's a guide at best. Sometimes completely wrong. But that is just how I interpret the values there.

Comment: @Trendfischer If memory is the issue and if you want to use `end` only, then you can create a wrapper class which implements `ArrayAccess` and have an additional function which returns an `end` of the internal private array that would be operated.

Comment: Question: what is the purpose of `array_keys` ? why don't you just cast it directly `$arr = (array) $array` and then `$end = end($arr)`

Answer (score 0):

A slightly faster approach without casting or using an iterator would be to not use the constructor in the first place, and instead use `append` method which will create an array itself and you can use `end` on that array later

```
$array = new \ArrayObject();
$array->append(["a", "b"]);
$item =  end($array[count($array) - 1]);
var_dump($item);
```

`count($array) - 1` in case you append another array later, we make sure that `$item` is always the last element in the last appended array.

Comment: Thanks, the solution with `count()` might be helpful in some cases, but your example would not work for something like this `new \ArrayObject([123 => "a", 456 => "c"]);`

Comment: @Trendfischer I know that's why I used `append` instead of the constructor, using append with your example will definitely work. `$array->append([123 => "a", 456 => "c"]`

Comment: @Trendfischer Please note `count` is not for the elements of your array it's for the multidimensional array that `append` will create. For your array we are using `end` as usual.

Comment: I appreciate the intention, but I usually do not use an ArrayObject as a simple replacement for an array. The example in the question is exemplary to show the problem. Although if I only use `append()`, I could use a `count()`, that is valid solution. That could work with `append('a')` and `append('b')`. The key would be to disallow associative arrays which is a possibility by extending ArrayObject.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this approach.

Should perform better than any of the above.

- No casting to another variable using memory and CPU
- Only one internal iterator.
- Only one new variable, and it's a reference to the item.

```php
class MyClass extends ArrayObject {
    public function last() {
        foreach ($this as $entity) {}
        return $entity ?? null;
    }
}

$array = new \MyClass(["a", "b", "c"]);
$item = $array->last();
var_dump($item);
```